# How to negate a boolean selection criteria

Tags: filtering

I know how to select from a list using a boolean function:

```
Select[list, MyFunctionQ]
```

But I can't figure out how to negate this. I've tried

```
Select[list, Not[MyFunctionQ]]
```

and several alternatives, but none have worked.

Comment: Use `Not @* MyFunctionQ`

Comment: also possible :  `Select[list, Not[MyFunction[#]]&]`

Comment: another possibility is `Select[myFunctionQ /* Not][list]`

Comment: @Carl Woll: I could not verify your hint. What does `@* mean? Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann If you are using M9 or previous, then you could do the equivalent `Composition[Not, MyFunctionQ]`.

Comment: @Carl Woll: Thank you., I use M11, but didn't find information concerning `@*`

Comment: @Carl Woll: I tried `MyFunctionQ[x_] := If[x > 0, True, False]` which evaluates to  `Not @* MyFunctionQ[3] (*Not@*True*)` different to  `Composition[Not, MyFunctionQ][-3](*True*)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Function application (e.g., f[x]) has higher precedence than `@*`, so `Not @* MyFunction[3]` is parsed as `Composition[Not, MyFunction[3]]`. This is not an issue when `Composition` is used as an argument to `Select`.

Comment: @Carl Woll: Thank you for your effort!